# Transactional Send Journey Event Definition Key

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, cloud

I see a bunch of transactional send journeys and I was wondering where the event defintion key comes from?

In Journey Builder under events - entry sources I can create an event and get the event defintion key which I can then plug into the event defintion in The transactional journey send - right?

But my current transactional journey's have event defintion keys that I cannot find at all in entry sources.  IS there another place in Marketing Cloud that generates event definition keys? Or alternatively is it possible that maybe an external source gave us the key?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you create a transactional journey, you can simply define the "event definition key" on the fly (by typing something into the Event Definition Key field).
This appears on the UI when setting up the transactional journey and clicking on the Transactional API Event:

[image]

==

Of course, you can use externally generated IDs in this field.

Comment: Hi Jonas I clicked the api event and it does not populate the event defintion key automatically - I also selected a triggered email - something I am doing wrong? The field is still blank

Comment: OK I will be more clear: You click on the grey circle. The Window on the left opens. In the Event Definition Key, you now get an input box - type in whatever you like, save. This is how the name is created for a transactional journey. edited my answer for clarity.

Comment: Ok thank you - So I think my client must have generated their own event key and put it in.  When I Create an entry source in Entry sources it gives me a different naming convention - thanks!